# How can add style to a button on every mouse down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that want to scale(1.5) every time that I click on the button,
now I use button:active in css to scale(1.5) my button but this command only one time gone to run and for another times I should click outside the button and then click on the button to scale(1.5), what can I do? please help me

```css
button:active {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button"> button</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Onclick CSS button effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312127/onclick-css-button-effect)

Comment: Something is probably missing, your CSS linked to a button works as it is.

Comment: when I click by mouse that works true but when I click with laptop's pad it does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
button {
  background: none;
}

button:active{
     transform: scale(1.5);
     background-color: red;
}

button:focus{
     transform: scale(1.5);
     background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: when I click by mouse that works true but when I click with laptop's pad it does not work

Comment: Hm Maybe Try Using Javascript fr it

Comment: If U Have Jquery Try

Comment: It Is Possible READ MY ANSWER

Comment: My project is react js and i can use javascript but I don't know how can possible this feature for mouse pad